# ein viertel Teelöffel Gewürznelken

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar-identification

> ein viertel Teelöffel *Gewürznelke*
>
> ein viertel Teelöffel *Gewürznelke**n***

How it will be decided that measured noun should be in singular or plural?

Comment: *Ein viertel Teelöffel Gewürznelken* sind in der Praxis allerdings *eine* Gewürznelke. Darum würde ich vermuten, de Autor spricht hier von Gewürznelkenpulver. Na gut, es kommt auch drauf an, wie groß der Teelöffel ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Während ich Dir im Prinzip zustimme, hat Deine Mengenangabe dem Koch in mir keine Ruhe gelassen und ich bin an meinen Küchenschrank gegangen: Je nach Größe und Geometrie passen in einen 1/4-Tl-Messlöffel sieben bis neun Nelken. ^_^ Außerdem vermute ich, das der Fragesteller eher wissen wollte, welchen Numerus er oder sie selbst benutzen sollte.

Comment: @Stephanie. Sprichst du nun von ganzen Nelken oder von Nelkenpulver (in deinem 1/4-Teelöffel-Messgerät)? Wenn wir von ganzen Nelken sprechen: Ich kann auf einem ganzen Teelöffel gerade mal so zehn Nelken herumbalancieren...

Answer (score 8):

It will depend on the substance and the speaker’s perception of it.

The singular form is used for uncountable masses - a quarter teaspoon honey - where the amount is seen as a part of a larger entity. Like a slice of bread can’t be baked as an independent piece, just cut off a whole loaf. But it can also mean the substance per se, independent of countability, used as mass noun.

If you use the plural from, your perception is that the entire amount is made up from multiple individual smaller entities - a carton of eggs.

Now in recipes you will find both, just within a very slight difference in meaning.

- If you see a teaspoon of *Nelken* without further details, you may assume *whole cloves* - they are clearly countable. The same would apply for *Pfefferkörner*.
- If the singular form “Nelke” is used, this information is missing, the speaker is talking about an part taken from a larger amount, like the content of the spice jar. In practical application, it will *often* refer to the spice in already ground form. (Traditional German cuisine isn’t used to handling whole spices except for maybe pepper, cloves and nutmeg, very different from, for example, Indian cuisine.) So if you read singular, the author of the recipe didn’t care, didn’t specify or considered “ground” as default.

Language-independent cooking advice: Be careful when navigating this minefield peppered with potential misunderstandings. A teaspoon of whole cloves will yield way less than a teaspoon of ground *and* be  more potent if ground up freshly.

Comment: _"Language-independent cooking advice"_ LOL, that's a good one. To become serious, a link to [SE Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) won't hurt.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. As an SA mod, I didn’t want to do overdo it ;-)

Comment: "Ein viertel Teelöffel X" würde man auch sagen, wenn ein einzelnes X schon mehr als ein viertel Teelöffel ist (ein viertel Teelöffel Kürbis, beispielsweise).

Answer (score 1):

It depends.
Let's say you have whole cloves, this would rather tend to be translated as

> ein viertel Teelöffel Gewürznelken

as plural.

If you have powdered cloves you'd rather say

> ein viertel Teelöffel Gewürznelke

As other examples, that question won't come up referring to

> ein viertel Teelöffel Curcuma(pulver) (usually not used as whole piece)

or

> ein viertel Teelöffel Wacholderbeer**en** (usually used as whole pieces)

Comment: elegant umformuliert ;-)